# How to pass objects in angular2 material's dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My dialog contains a form that populates an object "someresult" I want that object to be passed back to the app component after the user clicks "OK" on the dialog box. How do I do this?

I included a simple example in this PLUNKR.
http://plnkr.co/edit/qjpY6m5C8bgJjRfm4Yot?p=preview

```
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'confirm-dialog',
    template: `
        <p>{{ title }}</p>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>

        <button type="button" md-raised-button 
            md-dialog-close="someresult">OK</button>

        <button type="button" md-button 
            (click)="dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
    `,
})

    export class ConfirmDialog {

        public title: string;
        public message: string;
        public someresult = { // this is the object I want to pass back
          'key': 'somevalue'
        }

        constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ConfirmDialog>) {

        }
    }
```

In my app.component.ts I want to be abl eto log out the result using console.log, I can't seem to get the object to log out properly...

```
  public openDialog() {
    this.dialogsService
      .confirm('Confirm Dialog', 'Are you sure you want to do this?')
      .subscribe(res => {this.result = res; console.log(res.key);});
  }
```

Note that if I logged console.log(key), I see [Object object] in the console, but when I try to access the key "key", I get an undefined...

Comment: I was able to access the `key` value. See if this is correct? http://plnkr.co/edit/XsQaUtcliGQpm928iDrw?p=preview

Comment: Works, post as an answer and I will mark as correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to access `key` value. `?` safe navigation ignores `key` when it's `undefined` or `null`.

Edited [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XsQaUtcliGQpm928iDrw?p=preview) of your Plunker.